# GCC Reducing Binary Bloat -- Strange Side Effect

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, toolchain

**The Weirdness**

I have compiled Google Protocol Buffers using no extra parameters for a "bloat" compile, and compile with the following command `./configure CXXFLAGS="-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections"`. a du-h reveals:

```
120K ./bloat/bin
124K ./bloat/include/google/protobuf/io
8.0K ./bloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler/java
12K ./bloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler/python
8.0K ./bloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp
128K ./bloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler
52K ./bloat/include/google/protobuf/stubs
848K ./bloat/include/google/protobuf
852K ./bloat/include/google
856K ./bloat/include
12K ./bloat/lib/pkgconfig
37M ./bloat/lib
38M ./bloat
20K ./unbloat/bin
124K ./unbloat/include/google/protobuf/io
8.0K ./unbloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler/java
12K ./unbloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler/python
8.0K ./unbloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp
128K ./unbloat/include/google/protobuf/compiler
52K ./unbloat/include/google/protobuf/stubs
848K ./unbloat/include/google/protobuf
852K ./unbloat/include/google
856K ./unbloat/include
12K ./unbloat/lib/pkgconfig
15M ./unbloat/lib
16M ./unbloat
53M .
```

Drill Down:

```
 ls -gGh bloat/lib/
    total 37M
    -rw-r--r-- 1  13M 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1  986 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf.la
    -rw-r--r-- 1 1.6M 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf-lite.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 1021 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf-lite.la
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   25 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf-lite.so -> libprotobuf-lite.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   25 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf-lite.so.6 -> libprotobuf-lite.so.6.0.0
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 771K 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf-lite.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf.so -> libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf.so.6 -> libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 5.5M 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1  12M 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotoc.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 1.1K 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotoc.la
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotoc.so -> libprotoc.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotoc.so.6 -> libprotoc.so.6.0.0
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 4.6M 2010-09-07 13:57 libprotoc.so.6.0.0
    drwxr-xr-x 2 4.0K 2010-09-07 13:57 pkgconfig
    ls -gGh unbloat/lib/
    total 15M
    -rw-r--r-- 1 5.8M 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1  988 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf.la
    -rw-r--r-- 1 764K 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf-lite.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 1023 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf-lite.la
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   25 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf-lite.so -> libprotobuf-lite.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   25 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf-lite.so.6 -> libprotobuf-lite.so.6.0.0
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 393K 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf-lite.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf.so -> libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf.so.6 -> libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 2.7M 2010-09-07 14:03 libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 3.7M 2010-09-07 14:04 libprotoc.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 1.1K 2010-09-07 14:04 libprotoc.la
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 2010-09-07 14:04 libprotoc.so -> libprotoc.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 2010-09-07 14:04 libprotoc.so.6 -> libprotoc.so.6.0.0
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 1.3M 2010-09-07 14:04 libprotoc.so.6.0.0
    drwxr-xr-x 2 4.0K 2010-09-07 14:03 pkgconfig
```

**The Question**

I have not altered the build scripts to perform a "`--gc-sections`" during linking, therefore shouldn't the unbloat build be the same if not bigger ? What caused the reduction in size ?

**Background**

I am compiling a low-level library with gcc at the moment and the library is a ginormous 2.5MB unstriped and 970KB stripped. This is unacceptable, and I need to remove dead-code -- I depend on OpenSSL, Protocol Buffers and 3 Libraries from Boost, and I will static link the last 2 into my library. The two statically linked libraries will have to be compiled them with the "-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections" for me to remove dead code.

**Related Question**

My [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3659315/153865) is about how to specify the root used to eliminate dead code.

Comment: had to delete old post since I had a double post for some reason. Yes 2.5 MB is ginormous -- I have written similar libraries and can get them down to 80-300kb (using MSVC). The GCC toolchain should be able to do the same.

Comment: @Hassan Syed, I think your background section causes more problems than it resolves.  It doesn't relate to the question, and it makes it sound like you're asking for ways to reduce the file size of a binary.  I would remove it, or put it at the end of the question.

Comment: Well the un-strpped size does not count. As that contains all the extra stuff you want for de-bugging and is not really relevant to production.

Comment: I would start using readelf -s and readelf -S (capital) to compare the sections and symbols in those .so files.

Comment: GCC's info page says of these options: "When you specify these options, the assembler and linker will create larger object and executable files and will also be slower."

Comment: @Hassan Just wondering, your post suggested getting the binary size smaller, what was the final outcome of this? What was the final size you were able to get it down to using gcc? Were any additional technique's used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid the gain has nothing to do with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`: when you specified `CXXFLAGS="-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections"` on configure command line, you overwrote the default flags which were `-O2 -g -DNDEBUG`. As a consequence, your code was compiled with no optimizations.

You should redo your test with `CXXFLAGS="-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O2 -g -DNDEBUG"` and you will get the expected (i.e., identical) results.

Comment: He will *most certainly* not get identical results, but your theory about missing -O2 is somewhat plausible. However, if he really did compile without '-g', then his "bloat" should have been *much* smaller, which contradicts observed facts.

Comment: I checked my "theory" before posting :) Of course, the result won't be strictly identical (because cross-section calls will take place instead of PC-relative calls within the same object module) but the size difference will be very small. Concerning the "much smaller" issue, do not forget that code compiled with `-O0` is often larger than code compiled with `-O2`, which counterbalances a bit the absence of `-g`.

Comment: This does sound like the most likely cause, Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling with `-ffunction-sections` causes every function to be emitted into its own section, and that causes every object file to become larger (instead of just `.text` section, you now have `.text.foo`, `.text.bar`, etc.). Same for `-fdata-sections`. So the result you've got is exactly what's expected.

But you *shouldn't* care how big your build area is. What you *should* care about is how big your final executable (or shared library) is.

With the flags you've specified, the "bloat" executable may still be bigger (but probably not by much). Now add `-Wl,--gc-sections`, and your "bloat" executable will become markedly smaller.